# Running Node.js command produces no output and does not exit

Tags: javascript, node.js, ping, execution

so the following code isnt working for the ping command. Any suggestions?

```
var target = "8.8.8.8";
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { console.log(stdout) }
exec("ping 8.8.8.8", puts);
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: "Isn't working" doesn't tell us anything useful.  Are you getting errors?  Does it do nothing at all?  Be specific about what "doesn't work" means.  How are you running this code?  In a browser or in NodeJS, or something else?  (Aside: I love your avatar)

Comment: Oh sorry! Running in nodejs, and its getting no output but not exiting.

Comment: Why would it exit? ping hasn't exited.

Comment: @Quentin its exiting because there is no limit for pings, its pinging endless and will never print the result to stdout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var child = require('child_process').spawn('ping', ["8.8.8.8"]);
    child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
       console.log(data.toString('utf8'));            
    });

    child.stdout.on('end', function(data) {
       console.log('done')
    });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way i get the result updated in stdout? Because right now it sends me all 3 ping results after the third is done